# ЧПУ htaccess . Вопрос

Tags: php

Здравствуйте . 
есть выражения

```
RewriteRule ^alladv/q-(.*)/?$ index.php?m=doska&k=all_advert&q=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^alladv/q-(.*)/page([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?m=doska&k=all_advert&q=$1&page_alladvert=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Подскажите, почему запрос сайт.ру/alladv/q-text/page2.html воспринимается первым выражением ,а не вторым ? Если поменять местами, то все работает. Можно как-то по-другому сделать, чтобы не менять порядок ?

Comment: А порядок - это так принципиально?

Comment: нет , не принципиально , но просто хотелось бы знать, есть ли альтернатива, кроме порядка

Comment: Ну во всяком случае, я вижу одно решение - переставить местами. Может кто лучше это разбирал

Comment: В последнее время много вопросов с меткой ЧПУ. Это про что вообще? Я станки с ЧПУ знаю, а PHP с ЧПУ - это что?

Comment: @rjhdby человеко подобный урл если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: @ЮраПетров Человекоподобный урл!? В этой фразе прекрасно все. Мой бог! Сделайте меня развидеть это

Comment: Прошу прощение. Человекопонятный URL